# Decode and convert Marketo API response to DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have been stumped by this problem for 2 days and any help would be appreciated.  I can't seem to find a way to decode/convert a response I am getting back from the Marketo API into a Pandas dataframe.   Any help would be greatly appreciated.   These are the steps I am taking and the sample responses:

**1)  I get a response from Marketo, which is in a bytes format.  See snippet below.**

```
res = requests.get('https://REDACTED.mktorest.com/bulk/v1/program/members/export/36e24d36-0e05-4c00-907d-825b05612fc6/file.json?access_token=REDACTED')

res.content

b'id,status,program\n930966,Exit-Unengaged,Nurture_Marketplace_Business\n930967,Exit-Unengaged,Nurture_Marketplace_Business\n962544,Exit-Unengaged,Nurture_Marketplace_Business'
```

**2) It's in somewhat of a strange format, but I decode it which then turns it into a string object below.**

```
data = res.content.decode() 
data
    
'id,status,program\n930966,Exit-Unengaged,Nurture_Marketplace_Business\n930967,Exit-Unengaged,Nurture_Marketplace_Business\n962544,Exit-Unengaged,Nurture_Marketplace_Business'
```

**How can I convert this into a Pandas Dataframe, where the colum are id, status, program?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the step you already finished is decoding the string:

```
data = res.content.decode()
```

Split the data on the `\n`'s:

```
data = data.split()
```

For each line, split the comma-separated elements:

```
data = [elem.split(',') for elem in data]
```

Now we are ready to generate the `DataFrame`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data[1:4], columns=data[0])
print(df)
```

[image]